# How to generate openapi client from uri in Gradle

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, openapi-generator

I'm probably trying to do something strange, since this doesn't seem like a common question (or maybe I'm asking it all wrong). I was expecting this to be straightforward.

Basically, what I am looking for is a way to do the same as the following, except by using the gradle openapi-generator plugin:
`openapi-generator generate -i www.example.com/openapi-doc -g spring`

What I have tried is the following (and the associated errors):

> 1. inputSpec.set("www.example.com/openapi-doc") --> *Cannot convert URL {} to a file*
> 2. inputSpec.set(URL("www.example.com/openapi-doc").readText()) --> *specified for property 'inputSpec' does not exist*

The actual code looks something like this:

```kotlin
tasks.register<GenerateTask>("generateClient") {
    validateSpec
    generatorName.set("spring")
    library.set("spring-cloud")
//    inputSpec.set("$openapiSpecDir/client/openapi.json") <-- *I am currently using a file, which I don't want to do*
    inputSpec.set("https://www.example.com/openapi-doc")
    outputDir.set(generatedClientDir)
    apiPackage.set("org.example.api")
    modelPackage.set("org.example.model")
    skipOverwrite.set(false)
    templateDir.set("$rootDir/src/main/resources/openapi/templates/client")
    configOptions.put("java8", "false")
    configOptions.put("serializationLibrary", "jackson")
    configOptions.put("dateLibrary", "java8")
}
```

Comment: What Gradle plugin are you using?

Comment: Good point sorry.. I'm using  the openapi generator gradle plugin 5.0.0-beta3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're using the [OpenAPI Generator Gradle Plugin](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator-gradle-plugin), at the time of writing this answer, getting the `inputSpec` from a URL is not supported. However, for Maven this has been implemented ([Issue #2241](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/2241) closed with [PR #3826](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/pull/3826)), so chances are good to have it implemented with a feature request that gets the Gradle plugin on par with its Maven counterpart.

That being said, you may want to look into [Gradle Download Task](https://github.com/michel-kraemer/gradle-download-task). Gradle Download Task is a plugin that let's you download files from a URL. The downloaded file can be used to feed it into the OpenAPI generator.

Answer (score 0):

As of OpenAPI Generator Gradle Plugin Version 6.3.0 you can use 'remoteInputSpec' instead of 'inputSpec'. This allows you to define the URL to the spec. Furthermore you can provide auth settings via 'auth'.